# Laravel - Passport API integration | Error: {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am new to `Laravel`. I have just started learning `Laravel` passport integration using [this reference link](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-passport-create-rest-api-with-authentication).

Below is my route file `api.php`

```
Route::post('login', 'API\PassportController@login'); // this is working fine
Route::post('register', 'API\PassportController@register'); // this is working fine
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
   Route::post('get-details' , 'API\PassportController@getDetails'); // This is giving me error
});
```

`PassportController.php >> getDetails()` function code,

```
/**
 * details api
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getDetails()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

`config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

I have updated rest of the files as mentioned [in the article](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-passport-create-rest-api-with-authentication).

Registration and login APIs are working fine but when I try to run `/get-details` api, I am getting `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` in response.

In the headers I am passing values like below,
[image]

Strange thing is that same code is working fine at my localhost server (OS- Windows) but when I run this API on my hosting server (OS- ubuntu) then it does not work.

Could anyone help me in resolving this issue? Is this related to server configuration settings? I am even not able to debug this code to check where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try adding one more Key in header 'Content-Type' --  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' there might be luck

Answer (score 1):

Did u pass the api token in header. 
If not , first you have to pass login details to api and get the api token. Then pass this token to the request , which u r trying to ac ess .
Another possibility is u need to run the 
Passport install command  again if ur environment change from local to live

Comment: Yes i did actually. I first did login and get the access token and then pass it to the /get-details api via the header. I am passing header values like **Accept: application/json** , **Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>**. Also i ran commands directly on server to install fresh Laravel and passport. Do you think i should run the command again because i didn't upload the code? 
Thanks!!

Comment: @Jchauhan Did you ever solve this? what solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add Passport::routes(); in AuthServiceProvider

```
<?php

 namespace App\Providers;

 use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as 
 ServiceProvider;

 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
    //Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
    //
   }
}
```

Please refer this link
https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: Yes i did. I followed all the steps mentioned in the link https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-passport-create-rest-api-with-authentication. Please check and do let me know if i have missed something which is not mentioned in this article. Also I debug the code a bit and found that i am getting all the header parameter except "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" parameter. That is why it is unable to get the token. Could you just help me why is this happening??

Comment: edit your .htaccess file                                                                                            RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: Its already as per your code. Here is my current code,

RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
Is anything else do i need to update in .htacess file?

Comment: Amit - It is ignoring "Authorization" header parameter every time in the request. That is why token in not being sent. Could you please tell me what could be the reason that it is behaving like this??

Answer (score 1):

Add Below line in the controller,

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
```

And also, please try with below command,

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

**auth:api** middleware is expecting the request to come in via JSON.

It's looking for **X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest** in the incoming request headers. When it can't find it, it falls into the **unauthenticated** method in **app/Exceptions/Handler**, and returns an error.

If you add **X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest** to your request headers, it should resolve the issue.

Comment: It didn't work either. I debug the code myself and found that i am getting all the header parameter except "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" parameter. That is why it is unable to get the token. Could you just help me why is this happening? How can i pass the authorization parameter in header? I also checked my .htaccess file and i guess its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess file, may be there is some configuration issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing the package [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and adding the **Authorization** header in the **allowedHeaders** option provided by the package.

```
'allowedHeaders' => ['Authorization']
```

May be that can solve the header not sending problem.

or you may need to change the [apache](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#114877) setting

Comment: Could you please elaborate this point a bit? What actually do i have to change in apache settings?

Comment: You need to add this line to 
     `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1`
to your apache config file .
Also you need to restart the apache after making changes in config file

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, i added this code in controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
```

then run this command:
php artisan optimize:clear
and get my Auth::user()

Comment: The same answer has already been given before.